# Small oscillations of a dynamical system near stable equilibrium points

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, euler-lagrange-equation, hamilton-equations

I'm having problems solving this lagrangian dynamical system:
Let $P$ and $Q$ be two points in $\mathbb R^2$ s.t. $P\in\Gamma_1\equiv y=x^2$ and $Q\in\Gamma_2\equiv y=-x^2$.
The two points are connected by a spring of constant $k>0$, with rest lenght zero. I have to find the frequency of small oscillations in a neighbourhood of the stable equilibrium points, but I don't manage to deduce their staility. This is what I've done:
$$P=(u,u^2)\text{ and }Q=(v,-v^2)\\V(u,v)=mgu^2-mgv^2+\dfrac k2(d(P,Q))^2=mg(u^2-v^2)+\dfrac k2[(u-v)^2+(u^2-v^2)^2]\\ T(\dot u,\dot v)=\dfrac{m}{2}(\dot u^2+\dot v^2+4(u^2\dot u^2+v^2\dot v^2).$$
In order to find the points of equilibrium I imposed $\nabla V(u,v)=(0,0)$, which (I think) generates the solutions
$E=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2:u=v\}$. The Hessian of the potential is given by
$$D^2V=\begin{pmatrix}k[(2u^2+2uv+1)+(4u+2v)(u-v)]+2mg &&-k(2u^2+2uv+1)\\-k[(2u^2+2uv+1)+2u(u-v)]&&-k[-(2v^2+2uv-1)+(u-v)(4v+2u)]-2mg\end{pmatrix}$$
and now I should evaluate this matrix in $(u,v)\in E$, but it seems to be really tedious.
I always found stable equilibrium points of the form $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb R^2$ so I don't know how to find small oscillations via linearized Lagrange equation $D^2T\cdot\ddot q +D^2V\cdot q=0$ .

Comment: So you have two mass points fixed to a parabolic curve and situated on opposite branches of the parabola, connected with a spring that has a rest length equal to the distance of these points? And now you want acoustic solutions, that is small perturbations of the equilibrium?

Comment: Then the intro makes little sense. Or is the intention that the initial $x$ is very small, and the equilibrium is where $P=Q=$ origin? Making a second pass, the points move freely along separate, mirrored parabola, with gravity involved?

Comment: Exactly and without friction. About the equilibrium in the origin it's not specified. I suppose it wants me to find all the equilibrium points without any initial hypotesis concerning the equilibrium points of the system.

Comment: @LutzLehmann is the method I was following correct?

Comment: That is not how Lagrangian mechanics with (holonomic) constraints work.  You can't substitute directly $(u,u^2)$ and $(v,-v^2)$ directly, because you obviously have the wrong geometry of forces on the particles.  You need to work with a Lagrangian with Lagrangian multipliers $\mathcal{L}(q,\dot{q},t)-\sum_i\lambda_i(t)f_i(q,t)$, etc.

Comment: If I have a constraint defined by $x_n=f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}),$ with $f:\mathbb R^{n-1}\to \mathbb R, f\in\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^{n-1})$ shouldn't I consider the point on the constraint as $P(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})=(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}))$. During lessons we've always worked with surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$ and points defined by generalized coordinates of the form $(x,y,f(x,y))$...

Comment: You need to apply the Euler-Lagrange equations correctly. With $$L(x,v)=T(x,v)-V(x),$$ where $x$ is the state vector and in application $v=\dot x$ the velocity, you get from $$\frac{d}{dt}L_v(x,\dot x)=L_x(x,\dot x)$$ the equation
$$\frac{d}{dt}T_v(x,\dot x)=T_x(x,\dot x)-V_x(x).$$ IMO it makes no difference where you implement the constraints, but the calculation with Lagrange multipliers could be structurally more simple in some steps

Comment: Ok and if I want to find frequencies of small oscillations I have to solve $$\det(D^2V-\omega^2 D^2T)=0$$ right?

Comment: Only for the (instable?) equilibrium $P=Q=0$, that is, $u=v=0$. Stability there probably depends on the springs Hooke constant, a very weak spring may allow the lower point to glide away to the side if perturbed, while with a strong constant the points are glued together. For the other equilibrium positions the dependence of $T$ on $(u,v)$ will introduce additional terms with first-order derivatives.

Comment: So you didn't find $\nabla V(u,v)=(0,0)$ $\forall u,v\in\mathbb R^2 : u=v$

Comment: That is impossible, as the $y$ values are opposite, $u^2$ and $-v^2$, so the spring is not in neutral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, setting $\ddot u=\ddot v= \dot u=\dot v=0$ for a stationary solution, one finds that the ODE reduces to $∇V(u,v)=(0,0)$. In detail these equations read
\begin{align}
0&=2mgu+k(u-v)+2ku(u^2-v^2)\\
0&=-2mgv+k(v-u)+2kv(v^2-u^2)
\end{align}
Combining the equations to eliminate the third-degree terms gives
$$
0=2mg(u^2-v^2)+k(u-v)^2
$$
so that either $u=v$ leading to $u=v=0$, or
$$
0=2mg(u+v)+k(u-v)\implies v=-\frac{2mg+k}{2mg-k}u=-au
$$
Inserting into the first equation then gives
$$
0=2mgau+2ku^3(1-a^2)\\
u^2=\frac{mga}{k(a^2-1)}=\frac{4m^2g^2-k^2}{8k^2}
$$
So as conjectured in the comments, if $k$ is small enough, one gets additional non-zero stationary positions, at $k=2mg$ there is a fork bifurcation.

Comment: I found that the point is unstable